# Fibre bundle with a free and proper right-action that is isomorphic to the principal fibre bundle from the Quotient Manifold Theorem. Fibres = Orbits?

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

Suppose $\pi\colon P \to M$ is a fibre bundle, $(G,\bullet)$ a Lie group and $\triangleleft\colon P \times G \to P$ a (smooth) free and proper Lie group right action of $G$ on $P$. The *Quotient Manifold Theorem* then states that $\rho\colon P \to P/{\triangleleft G}, a \mapsto \operatorname{Orb}_{\triangleleft}(a) = a \triangleleft G$ is a principal bundle.

**My doubt is the following**:
I originally suspected that *if $\triangleleft$ preserves the fibres of $\pi\colon P \to M$ and if there exists a bundle isomorphism $\require{AMScd}\varphi\colon P \to P$ along $f\colon M \to P/{\triangleleft G}$, then $\pi\colon P \to M$ is a principal bundle with the property that its fibres are precisely given by the group orbits.*

Now, however, I find myself unable to prove that there exists a diffeomorphism $\tilde f\colon M \to P/{\triangleleft G}$ such that $\mathrm{id}_P\colon P \to P$ is a bundle isomorphism along $\tilde f\colon M \to P/{\triangleleft G}$.

I was intending to argue in the following way:

1. I can define a smooth map 
   $$F\colon P/{\triangleleft G} \to P/{\triangleleft G}, \quad a \triangleleft G \mapsto (\rho \circ \varphi)(a),$$
   which is well-defined since $\triangleleft$ preserves fibres and since $\rho \circ \varphi = f \circ \pi$. This map then satisfies $F \circ \rho = \rho \circ \varphi$.
2. Define a map
   $$\tilde F\colon P/{\triangleleft G} \to P/{\triangleleft G}, \quad a \triangleleft G \mapsto (\rho \circ \varphi^{-1})(a)$$
   and prove that it is well-defined, smooth and the inverse to $F$.
3. Then $\rho = F^{-1} \circ f \circ \pi$ follows, thus constructing a diffeomorphism $F^{-1} \circ f\colon M \to P/{\triangleleft G}$ such that $\mathrm{id}_P\colon P \to P$ is a bundle isomorphism along $F^{-1} \circ f\colon M \to P/{\triangleleft G}$.

In order to prove well-definedness in **Step 2**, it looks like I would have to require from the beginning that the fibres of $\pi\colon P \to M$ are precisely given by the group orbits. Yet, intuitively it feels to me like this assumption shouldn't be necessary.

Is my intuition actually valid? If so, how do I prove the statement? Or does there exist a counterexample?

### Edit 1: Topological Complications?

Let us look at the following modification of the question above:

Suppose $\pi\colon P \to M$ is a fibre bundle with a (smooth) free and proper Lie group right action $\triangleleft\colon P \times G \to P$ of $G$ on $P$ such that $\triangleleft$ preserves the fibres of $\pi\colon P \to M$. Is it possible that there exists a bundle isomorphism $\varphi\colon P \to P$ along $f\colon M \to P/{\triangleleft G}$ while there does not exist a diffeomorphism $\tilde f\colon M \to P/{\triangleleft G}$ such that $\mathrm{id}_P\colon P \to P$ is a bundle isomorphism along $\tilde f$?

#### Example: (smooth) free and proper $U(1)$-action on two disjoint cylinders as total space

Consider the following example. The total space $P$ shall be given as the disjoint union of two cyliners with the base space $M = (-1,1)$ being an open interval. Suppose we have a fibre-preserving, free and proper right-action of $U(1)$ on the total space. Then the orbit space $P/{\triangleleft G}$ has 2 connected components while the base space $M$ is connected. Therefore no bundle isomorphism between $\rho\colon P \to P/{\triangleleft G}$ and $\pi\colon P \to M$ can exist. Refer to the sketch below:
[image]
Does this argument hold true in the general case as well, stating that there cannot exist a bundle isomorphism whatsoever, if at least one fibre is given as the disjoint union of at least two orbits?

Answer (score 1):

I think your intuition is valid. I believe you can define an inverse of your function $f:M\to P/{\triangleleft G}$ as follows: define $h:P/{\triangleleft G}\to M$ by $h(a\triangleleft G) := \pi(\varphi^{-1}(a))$. $h$ is well-defined since the group action preserves fibres of $\pi:P\to M$, as does $\varphi^{-1}$. It is smooth, since locally it can be written as $h\vert_U = \pi\circ\varphi^{-1}\circ s$, where $s:U\to P$ is some local section of $\rho:P\to P/{\triangleleft G}$. It can be checked that $f\circ h = \mathrm{id}_{P/{\triangleleft G}}$ and $h\circ f =\mathrm{id}_M$. So $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

Edit: if I'm understanding the example in your edit correctly, it seems to me that $P/{\triangleleft G}$ would consist of two copies of $(-1,1)$  (one for each cylinder). You say this, but it's not reflected in your picture. Then I'm not sure what you mean by "a bundle isomorphism between $\rho:P\to P/{\triangleleft G}$ and $\pi:P\to M$" in this context, since a bundle isomorphism of principal bundles will only exist if the fibres are isomorphic, which is not true in your case. Unless your definition of principal bundle isomorphism is different to mine?

Edit 2: we have by assumption
\begin{CD}
P @>{\varphi}>> P \\
@VV{\pi}V @VV{\rho}V\\
M @>{f}>>P/{\triangleleft G}
\end{CD}
Assuming you accept the fact that $f$ has an inverse $h = f^{-1}$ (I'm still not clear whether you do),  $f$ is a diffeomorphism.
Since $\varphi$ is a bundle isomorphism, we also have
\begin{CD}
P @>{\varphi}>> P \\
@VV{\pi}V @VV{\pi}V\\
M @>{\check{\varphi}}>>M
\end{CD}
for some diffeomorphism $\check{\varphi}$. Combining these two diagrams gives
\begin{CD}
P @>{\mathrm{id}_P}>> P \\
@VV{\pi}V @VV{\rho}V\\
M @>{f\circ\check{\varphi}^{-1}}>>P/{\triangleleft G}
\end{CD}
and $f\circ\check{\varphi}^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism. So it acts as your searched for $\tilde{f}$.

Comment: Your function $h\colon P/{\triangleleft G} \to M$ is inverse to what $f\colon M \to P/{\triangleleft G}$?

Comment: I assumed by hypothesis that diffeomorphisms $\varphi\colon P \to P$ and $f\colon M \to P/{\triangleleft G}$ exist such that $\varphi$ is a bundle isomorphism along $f$. 
Then, due to well-definedness (and smoothness) of $F$, I can only define a modified map $f^{-1} \circ F\colon P/{\triangleleft G} \to M, a \triangleleft G \mapsto (f^{-1} \circ \rho \circ \varphi)(a)$. So wouldn't I need to construct another map from $M \to P/{\triangleleft G}$ as its inverse?
That part of my question was not very well formulated, I fear.

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost now. As you say, you assumed the existence of a map $f:M\to P/{\triangleleft G}$. That's the $f$ I'm referring to in my answer. The point of my answer was to show the existence of a map $f^{-1}:P/{\triangleleft G}\to M$ (which I called $h$).

Comment: Well, I wanted to prove that $\pi\colon P \to M$ is a principal bundle. To my knowledge, this only follows if the action of $G$ on $P$ is free and the fibres are precisely given by the group orbits. This is a stronger condition than requiring the action to preserve the fibres.

Comment: If all you know is that $\pi:P\to M$ is a fibre bundle, and that the $G$-action on $P$ preserves the fibres of $\pi$, then no you cannot deduce that $P$ is a principal bundle. But it seemed you were assuming additional conditions in your original question. With these additional conditions, one can deduce the result. So do you assume the additional conditions or not?

Comment: Everything that is stated there yes. My original question indeed was if given a fibre bundle $\pi\colon P \to M$ that is endowed with a (smooth) free and proper right-action $\triangleleft\colon P \times G \to P$ that preserves the fibres of $\pi\colon P \to M$ and given that there exists a bundle isomorphism (not a principal bundle isomorphism) $\varphi\colon P \to P$ along $f\colon M \to P/{\triangleleft G}$. If then we can conclude that $\pi\colon P \to M$ is a principal bundle as well. 
This doesn't seem obvious to me anymore.

Comment: I've added a second edit to my answer - does this now address your question?

Comment: Yes, and now all of your answer does! I'm sorry, you just helped me realize that I was indeed very misleading. According to standard language a bundle isomorphism $\varphi\colon P \to P$ along a map $f\colon M \to P/{\triangleleft G}$ by no means implies that $f$ is needed to be a diffeomorphism, as I now understand. I was being lead by the assumption that bundle isomorphisms have the meaning of isomorphisms in the categorical sense... (and it feels to me like an isomorphism in the category of smooth fibre bundles should require their total and base spaces to be diffeomorphic...?)

Comment: As to Edit 2: Yes I assume $f$ to be a diffeomorphism. Am I right that you obtain the second diagram using a map $\Pi\colon P/{\triangleleft G} \to M, a \triangleleft G \mapsto \pi(a)$ that is smooth since for a local section $s\colon U \to P$ of $\rho\colon P \to P/{\triangleleft G}$ we have $\Pi\vert_U = \pi \circ s$? Then $\tilde \varphi = \Pi \circ f$? Then I don't see why $\tilde \varphi$ is a diffeomorphism, given that $\Pi\colon P/{\triangleleft G} \to M$ might map two orbits onto the same point $p \in M$. I didn't assume $\triangleleft$ to act transitively on the fibres,

Comment: Just to check terminology: I naively assumed that what is meant by an action that preserves fibres is that for each $g \in G$, we have $\pi \circ (\triangleleft g) = \pi$?

Comment: I interpreted your question as meaning "suppose we have a bundle morphism $\varphi$ (of the bundle $\pi:P\to M$, so in the sense of my second diagram), which also covers $f:M\to P/{\triangleleft G}$ (my first diagram, without assuming $f$ to be a diffeomorphism), and in addition the $G$-action preserves the fibres of $\pi:P\to M$". Then one can show that $f$ is in fact a diffeomorphism, and so $\pi:P\to M$ and $\rho:P\to P/{\triangleleft G}$ are isomorphic as bundles. (And yes, I believe bundle isomorphism requires the base spaces to be diffeomorphic.)

Comment: To your second comment, no. The second diagram is essentially my definition of $\varphi$ being a bundle isomorphism of $\pi:P\to M$ (really, the existence of $\check{\varphi}$ follows from the facts that $\varphi$ preserves fibres of $\pi:P\to M$, and that $\pi$ is a submersion). Although I understand now this may not have been your intended interpretation of "bundle isomorphism". To your third comment, yes, I took the same definition of the action preserving the fibres of $\pi:P\to M$.